# Android app has stopped working: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android

When I run my app it says "The app keeps stopping", and in the logcat I get this error: 2019-12-30 19:00:40.846 13687-13694/? E/zygote: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
2019-12-30 19:00:41.279 13687-13687/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ddanews, PID: 13687
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ddanews/com.example.ddanews.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{d03edbe VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.example.ddanews.MainActivity@1e99f0d
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{d03edbe VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.example.ddanews.MainActivity@1e99f0d
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{d03edbe VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.example.ddanews.MainActivity@1e99f0d
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:4304)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.ddanews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Please don't post the image of Code instead of Post the code directly and please provide declaration of recyclerview

Comment: Add activity xml code

Comment: Please show your `RecyclerView` inside `XML` and in your `Activity`. It doesn't match.

Comment: Hi Oxana, kindly share us the code snippet of `recyclerView` declaration at the top level of your code. It would also be helpful if you share us a snippet of your XML code showing the implementation of the `RecyclerView`. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) should also give you and idea how to properly add code in your SO question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple type cast error so just import the correct recyclerview.

As it show RecyclerView should be androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.

1. Your project should be on AndroidX if you are using androidx package
2. If you use any other dependency for recyclerview then remove it and recompile the code.

   ```
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/rvView"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   ```

Comment: Do you mean i should put that in activity_main:xml?

Comment: @OxanaPetrovic You have to put this in the layout file which have Recyclerview and implement androix dependency in app gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is not fully detailed but i'm pretty sure you're casting a wrong Library for your app.

There is 1 thing to check base on your images. in your xml you should check your RecyclerView library, then in your activity or adapter or etc make sure your using same library.

in your case you used RecyclerView, but my guess is that you casted or imported RecyclerListView. so double check your library. where-ever you assigned that recyclerView in activity, you should fix your problem from there.

```
// you should check this line in global before onCreate
RecyclerView recyclerView;

// then in Activivty.
recyclerView = (RecyclerVeiw) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) // Or
recyclerView = findViewByd(R.id.recyclerView)
```

Good Luck

Comment: Did not work... Thanks anyway Atlas!

Comment: @OxanaPetrovic Share your XML & activity and adapter code. base on your error looks like u've got another problem except what i've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is crashing because of the incorrect class type.

From the documentation:

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

For example, the following code generates a `ClassCastException`:

```java
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```

In your declaration, you may have placed `RecycleListView` instead of `RecyclerView` as the type of the `recyclerView` variable like this:

```java
RecyclerListView recyclerView;
```

Please try to verify that both implementation and usage of the list you added there are both `RecyclerView` (XML and Java class).

```xml
RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

This [article](https://airbrake.io/blog/java-exception-handling/classcastexception) should help you understand more what you are encountering.

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work... I gues I am missing something

Comment: Can you please share your XML as well in the post? Thank you.